# SQL Server User Permission?

Tags: sql-server

Sorry my English a little.

I created an application using C# and Sql server.

I create 2 users.

- user1: Has all permission as an admin account
- user2: Has only select permissions.

I choosing user2 on the c# application.

My customers using application from user2 account.

My question is:
I am test decompile my c# application and view sql connection code and login the my remote database.

How to give permission level user2 for c# select worked fine but sql server management studio can't login and view my tables?

Thank you for help.

Comment: What is wrong with user2 only have `SELECT` permissions?  Anything that you would want to test in SSMS, you could put `EXECUTE AS LOGIN = 'user2';` before it